# how to use the array-sort npm package in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to sort the array values in ionic2. I installed npm array-sort package in my project.Link:: I used to [sort array values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-sort)

How to use this code?

```
npm install --save array-sort
```

[image]

It gives error in 'require'

[image]

Comment: do you have @types installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

this dependency in your project.